# Apache Authentication for external access, but not for local access

Tags: apache, authentication

I need that my Apache require authentication only to external access but free in my local network. I have mod_user in my Apache.

Answer (score 2):

The ***easiest*** way to deal with this is to use two virtual host. Use one for the external users and one of the internal users... i.e. "www.myhost.com" for external and "www-int.myhome.com" for internal users. Restrict www-int to internal IP's only with no auth requirements.

Alternatively, you can use something like this in your Auth directives:

```
Require valid-user
Allow from 192.168.1
Satisfy Any
```

Answer (score 1):

Not much into apache authentication, i just use tomcat from time to time to test some jsp.

Have you tried reading this? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/howto/auth.html#basicconfig